# Integration multiple functions

Tags: r

Assume you have the following code

```
X = cbind(5,3,4)
func <- function(t){
   return(X*t)
}
```

Then func(5) results in the vector (25,15,20)

Now I want to solve the three integrals `int(5t,dt,0,5)`, `int(3t,dt,0,5)` and `int(4t,dt,0,5)`. Unfortunately, this does not work with

```
integrate(func,lower=0,upper=10)$value
```

Can someone help me how I can do this without a for loop?

Comment: can you please explain what int(5t,dt,0,5) means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK now I understand.

you can define func to return a function somthing like this

```
func <- function(t){
    function(v){v*t}
}
```

now `func(5)` returns a function that multpies its argument with 5

```
t <- func(5)
t(5)
[1] 25
```

now to integrate the three functions you can use lapply

```
lapply(X,function(t){integrate(func(t),0,5)})
```

If more variables are needed you can change the code accordingly

```
func <- function(V,y,w){
    function(t){1/V * pmax.int(-c, pmin.int((y-t)/V,c))*w}
}
```

only with the list do we need to trix around a bit. I am using the package purrr here to make a list of list each list containg one set of the different variables.

```
V = c(1,2,3) ;c = 2; y = c(5,6,7); w = c(8,9,10); z = c(8,10,11) 
L <- list(V = V,y = y, w = w,z = z)
L2 <- L %>% transpose()
```

The final call of the lapply will then look like this.

```
lapply(L2,function(vars){integrate(func(vars$V,vars$y,vars$w),vars$y,vars$z)})
```

Comment: Is it right that this solution can't be applied in the case you want to integrate each element of the following vector, with respect to t, and everytime the same boundaries?

1/V * pmax.int(-c, pmin.int((y-t)/V,c))*w

where V, y and w are vectors of the same length and c is an integer

Comment: Hi Chis, I cannot really understand what you want to do. Maybe if you could formulat the function as you would in R I could help you better.

Comment: I don't know if the functions are integrablefor this specific example, but it shows the idea. Define
V = c(1,2,3)
c = 2
y = c(5,6,7)
w = c(8,9,10)
z = c(8,10,11)
then I want the following integrals (without a for loop if possible)
integrate 1/V[i] * pmax.int(-c, pmin.int((y[i]-t)/V[i],c))*w[i] from y[i] till z[i]

so in this case, the integrals would be 
int(1/1 * pmax.int(-2, pmin.int((5-t)/1,2))*8, lower =5 ,upper=8)
int(1/2 * pmax.int(-2, pmin.int((6-t)/2,2))*9, lower =6 ,upper=10)
int(1/3 * pmax.int(-2, pmin.int((7-t)/3,2))*10, lower =7 ,upper=11)

Comment: I am correct wenn you now want to run over four different varibles V,y,w, and z

Comment: yes! But I want to run over them 'together' so V[i] is always with y[i], w[i] and z[i], never with for example z[i+1]

Comment: Hi Chris, did you look at my extended answer?

Comment: Oh no I didn't notice it! Thanks a lot, it works! :D